# Eclipse Luna Freezes during Google Play Services Android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I'm trying to use Google Play services in my app because I need Google Maps, but eclipse don't work, he freezy and block, something like memory heap full. I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing , and resolved after I edit the file eclipse.ini

```
  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```